# How do I know if I am inside a React router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am developing a web browser extension that renders various links. These links may be rendered either inside an "application" path (`app.html` in the extension), or from the browser action window (the extension button in the menu bar).

The application has a React router defined; the popup does not.

When I render the link in the application itself, I can use:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

<Link to={...}>Foo</Link>
```

However, in the popup itself, this does not work, as I get the error:

> `Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

This makes sense of course. But I would like to create links via a helper function or component, and how can I determine whether I am currently "inside" a router?

Note that I could in principle pass down a prop that tells the component explicitly whether it is part of a router or not, but that seems very verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine if you have a Router component in the hierarchy by trying to obtain the history object using `useHistory` hook

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const Comp = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    if(!history) {
       // no router in hierarchy
     }
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)